# How to adjust the number of images per row in icon view? (Finder)

Tags: finder, photos, macos

In the Finder, when using the icon view:

[image: Gallery view]

...is there a way to adjust the number of images displayed per row? Ideally, I'd want only as many images per row as fit in the window *without* scrolling horizontally.

For example, with an icon size of 364x364, the Finder is displaying 19 images per row. But only 4 fit. Meaning: I need to scroll horizontally constantly, which is a waste of time:

[image: Finder gallery view scrolling on and on and on...]
*Scrolling on and on and on...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't appear to be using Gallery View. That's Icon View. Gallery view is the 4th option on those buttons.

Gallery view shows the entire folder of images in a scroll-bar along the bottom, with the selected image expanded to fit the remaining space. e.g. -

[image]

To make Icon View fit the window horizontally, use View menu > Sort by or View menu > Clean up by [anything other than None].

Comment: I just renamed the question for clarity. My point is to see lots of thumbnails without having to scroll horizontally. A simple *Clean up* from the right-click menu does not work, but your two options do work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the View menu `cleanup` command when in icon view, which I think was your original question.